# Does zooming by touch change the viewport size?

Tags: html, css

I tried zooming in a webpage **by touch** instead of using `Ctrl +` and seems like the elements remains to be in same size but the screen is just zoomed, I assume that it does not change the size of viewport.

While using `Ctrl +` for same it orients from desktop view to mobile view if zoomed in too much and the elements adjust.

How does the **viewport** works when touch by zoom on webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to check the size of your viewport at any point:

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
```

The answer may vary between devices and browsers..